# how to configure proxy in .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am facing problem while calling **gcp api's (Vertex Ai & Bigquery)**. we have been using these api's from last few months. The behavior is unpredictable, sometimes we get api response successfully and sometimes its failing.

what we noticed that the same host **us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com** communication is disrupted.

Currently we are connecting with **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**.

I want to go through proxy. any suggestions ? or any other way I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the communication on the API call is interrupted due to a time out.
Unfortunately there is no way to authenticate using proxy unless you were using CloudSQL, but there are other ways to authenticate such as:

- Application Credentials (The way you are currently doing the authentication).
- [API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).
- [Oauth 2.0 Client Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user).
- [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account).

The recommended way to authenticate is using Application credentials.